# Parsley Date Format

Tags: javascript, parsley.js

I am currently setting up a form with a `<input type=date>` field with Parsley to validate that the date cannot be in the past. However, I am unable to get it to validate despite giving it the correct values(in the future). It seems to read the minimum value from the min field but I tried changing the formats around(e.g Y/m/d) but the error still pops up. Can I know what is the issue behind this and what is the workaround to it? Thanks in advance.

The error is `This value should be greater than or equal to 10/21/2014.` even though I gave it a date later than that.

```
<input type="date" name="contact-date" id="contact-date" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" data-date-format="mm/dd/yyyy" min="<?php echo date('m/d/Y'); ?>" parsley-type="dateIso">
```

I looked through K D's answer and realized that the regex was for DD/MM/YYYY so I changed it from

`/^([12]\d|0[1-9]|3[01])\D?(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\D?(\d{4})$/` to

`/^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\D?([12]\d|0[1-9]|3[01])\D?(\d{4})$/`

Somehow this changed to any date passed is a valid date despite the min value being specified.

Code is now:

```
<input type="date" class="contact-input" name="contact-date" id="contact-date" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" data-type="dateIso" data-parsley-min="<?php echo date('m/d/Y'); ?>">
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`parsley-type="dateIso"` tells me that you are using [Parsley v1.*](http://parsleyjs.github.io/Parsley-1.x/documentation.html) which is deprecated. `data-date-format="mm/dd/yyyy"` tells me that you are using [Bootstrap Datetimepicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/).

I suggest you use Parsley 2.x (even if it you need to craft the validator for min date) and use the attribute `data-date-minDate` of Datetimepicker.

For this solution, you need the following code ([**working jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/milz/ffjb5b31/2/)):

```
<div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker'>
    <input type='text' name="contact-date" id="contact-date"
        placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY"
        data-date-format="MM/DD/YYYY"
        data-date-minDate="<?php echo date('m/d/Y'); ?>"
        data-parsley-mindate="<?php echo date('m/d/Y'); ?>" />
    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
</span>
</div>

<script>
window.ParsleyValidator
    .addValidator('mindate', function (value, requirement) {
        // is valid date?
        var timestamp = Date.parse(value),
            minTs = Date.parse(requirement);

        return isNaN(timestamp) ? false : timestamp > minTs;    
    }, 32)
    .addMessage('en', 'mindate', 'This date should be greater than %s');

$('#myForm').parsley();

$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    language:'en'
});
</script>
```

Notes:

- `data-date-format` should be `MM/DD/YYYY` (uppercase, check [momentjs docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/));
- Replace `parsley-type="dateIso"` with `data-parsley-mindate="<?php echo date('m/d/Y'); ?>" />` so the custom validator is executed

Comment: Hi. Your fiddle isn't working on my side though. And must the input be a text field instead of a date field? Thanks a lot!

Comment: My bad, fiddle updated here: http://jsfiddle.net/milz/ffjb5b31/2/. I prefer using `text` instead of `date` to prevent the default datepicker of Chrome.

Comment: This worked beautifully. But what happened to editing the regex? Did moment.js handle this?

Comment: You don't need regex nor you need to edit the source code for Parsley (as a matter of fact, this is not a good idea). All the "magic" is done with `return isNaN(timestamp) ? false : timestamp > minTs;`. This is where it checks if the given date is greater than `data-parsley-mindate`. Also, if you enter a non-valid date it will return false as `Date.parse()` will return not a number.

Comment: Hi @LuísCruz , the parsley website is frustrating. No where on there does it give this information. Is there a better website to get direct knowledge like this? Also what is the string to create a custom date message? Thanks